# Instagram Media Search Comes Back with No Results

Tags: instagram-api

When I run the following url to access Instagram media search:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=37.775&lng=-122.4183333&access_token=MyAccessToken

I get the response below from Instagram:

```
    {"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}
```

Don't know why I am not getting the detailed media search results back. This url is similar to the example provided in the Instagram/Developer webpage: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

Answer (score 3):

First question would be, are you running your app in Sandbox mode or Live mode?

If you are running in Sandbox mode and you registered your app after November 17th, then you most likely only have permission to fetch data from users that accepted your invitation to Sandbox. Therefore, you wont be able to get public content even if you specified public_content scope.

Take a look at [official documentation page](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) in the top corner you will find the [announcement](http://prntscr.com/9bqdrd) .